# Regex to access digits between two underscores

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to access the number between two underscores. For example in the below text,

```
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929091__2.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929092__2.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929090__1.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929092__2.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__1205024__1.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929090__1.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929092__2.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__1205024__1.0
```

I need to get only the numbers 929091, 929092 etc.

I tried `'_(.*)_'` but I get the underscores too. I just need the number

Comment: `re.findall(r'_(\d+)_', text)`

Comment: Something like [`_(\d+)_`](https://regex101.com/r/L9A3hm/1)? Matches one or more digits between underscores.

Comment: re.findall(r'(?<=_)(\d+)(?=_)', text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'__([0-9]+)__', s)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/3sUPEr/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  __                       '__'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  __                       '__'
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##vZBBCsIwEEX3OUXopi3adBrrIoInERmK1qSQJmE6Cp4@6g3sQld/83g8fnqyi2GX8zSnSCxpFIs8SiqKwjGn5dC2n21sjNaPjXVOPYa7Z3WJM6LRBkyHqBWIb3G9DgfE7if2TsMedL9O/5ea9/ci0RS4olHdpnAdvK@oRKxO0JjzpkYst3Kp65xf)**:

```py
import re
s = r"""https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929091__2.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929092__2.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929090__1.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929092__2.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__1205024__1.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929090__1.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__929092__2.0
https://http-google-ghh.vault.com__1205024__1.0"""
print(re.findall(r'__([0-9]+)__', s))
```

**Results**: `['929091', '929092', '929090', '929092', '1205024', '929090', '929092', '1205024']`

Comment: It prints the underscores too. I just need the numbers. Is there any way to do it just to get the numbers and not the underscores?

Comment: @IttyBit Code added. No underscores. How do you see the underscores?

Comment: Thank you so much. I was running in Redshift and saw the underscores.